# create new pandas column starting at 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a new column in pandas called 'index', which incrementally adds a number for each row.

```
idx = 0
df.insert(idx, 'index', value=range(1,len(df)+ 1))
```

However, my index currently starts at 1 and I would like to change it to start at 0.

Current Output:

```
'index'
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
  ...
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Don't name your column `'index'`.  That is a reserved attribute that refers to a dataframe's index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `range(df)`:

```
idx = 0
df.insert(idx, 'index', value=range(len(df)))
```

Or for better performance:

```
df.insert(idx, 'index', value=np.arange(len(df)))
```

If want add column to last one:

```
df = df.assign('index', value=np.arange(len(df)))
```

---

```
df['index'] = np.arange(len(df)
```

But if want select this column is necessary use `[]`:

```
print (df['index'])
```

because with dot notation it select index:

```
print (df.index)
```